# How to find records based on a logical rule in R

Tags: r, filtering, data-cleaning

I have a data set with `ID` and `Year` as identifiers. I want to separate the rows that we don't have their previous year record, i.e, I want to find `B` from `A`:

```
A = 
ID    Year    x    y
1     2010    1    2
1     2011    2    2
1     2014    4    1
2     2013    2    3
2     2014    1    2

B =
ID    Year    x    y
1     2010    1    2
1     2014    4    1
2     2013    2    3
```

I can get that with the following `if loop`, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it! In the following code, I first sort `A` by `ID` and `Year` to detect the first data entry for each `ID`.

```
B <- A_sort[1,]
for(i in 2:nrow(A_sort)){
    if(A_sort$ID[i] != A_sort$ID[i-1]){
        B <- rbind(B,A_sort[i,])
    }else if(A_sort$Year[i] != A_sort$Year[i-1]+1){
        B <- rbind(B,A_sort[i,])
    }
}
```

Data (thanks @chinsoon12)

```
A <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 
    2014L, 2013L, 2014L), x = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L), y = c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "Year", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))
```

Comment: `A[ave(A$Year, A$ID, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))) != 1, ]`

Answer (score 0):

use diff to calculate the years lagged between rows? Then choose those without prev year record

```
A <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 
    2014L, 2013L, 2014L), x = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L), y = c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "Year", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))

library(plyr)
ddply(A[order(A$ID, A$Year),], .(ID), function(x) {
    yearLag <- c(0,diff(x$Year))
    x[yearLag != 1, ]
})
```